# jQuery works on first forloop and not working on other forloop element in Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I'm using [W3widgets calendar](http://w3widgets.com/responsive-calendar) and I want to set the dates dynamically through Python/Django. After inputting the value tag in the JavaScript hook, it only selects one date and there are more than one date entries. How can I make it select all date entries and display on the calendar?

Below are the html/JavaScript code and the source code.

HTML:

```
 <!-- Responsive calendar - START -->
    <div class="responsive-calendar">
    <div class="controls">
        <a class="pull-left" data-go="prev"><div class="btn btn-primary">Prev</div></a>
        <h4><span data-head-year></span> <span data-head-month></span></h4>
        <a class="pull-right" data-go="next"><div class="btn btn-primary">Next</div></a>
    </div><hr/>
    <div class="day-headers">
      <div class="day header">Mon</div>
      <div class="day header">Tue</div>
      <div class="day header">Wed</div>
      <div class="day header">Thu</div>
      <div class="day header">Fri</div>
      <div class="day header">Sat</div>
      <div class="day header">Sun</div>
    </div>
    <div class="days" data-group="days">

    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Responsive calendar - END -->
</div>

<!--where Django for loop starts -->
 {% for bring_out_date in bring_out_dates %}

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".responsive-calendar").responsiveCalendar({
      time: '2014-05',
      events: {
      //here's the tag I'm talking about
        "{{ bring_out_date.booked_dates|date:"Y-m-d"}}": {"number":  {{bring_out_date.id}}}}
      });
    });
 </script>

{% empty %}

    <p> no date selected. update your calendar </p>

    {% endfor %}
```

How it looks in the source code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".responsive-calendar").responsiveCalendar({
      time: '2014-05',
      events: {
        "2014-03-11": {"number":12}}
    });
  });
 </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".responsive-calendar").responsiveCalendar({
      time: '2014-05',
      events: {
        "2014-03-12": {"number":13}}
    });
  });
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".responsive-calendar").responsiveCalendar({
      time: '2014-05',
      events: {
        "2013-01-09": {"number":31}}
    });
  });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".responsive-calendar").responsiveCalendar({
      time: '2014-05',
      events: {
        "2014-04-03": {"number":15}}
     });
   });
  </script>


 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
     $(".responsive-calendar").responsiveCalendar({
      time: '2014-05',
      events: {
        "2014-04-09": {"number":19}}
     });
   });
 </script>
```

How can I make it select all date entries and display them on the calendar? Could this be jQuery not selecting all other forloop?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but the only thing that makes sense to me would be putting that loop *inside* the responsive calendar initialization, so that you end up with a list of events and not a bunch of redundant re-initializations of the calendar.

Comment: how will I go about that? Can you write the code example?

Comment: I don't know anything about django or python. My suggestion is just to put that template loop around the "events" property of that initialization, so that you end up with a list of separate events inside a single call to the responsive calendar initialization.

Comment: It won't wwork because it will see it as a javascript property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work by putting the for loop inside the event: feeder -

```
events: {
{% for vDate, vClass, vBadges in cal_list %}
"{{vDate}}": {"class":"{{vClass}}", {% if vBadges != 0 %}"number": "{{vBadges}}",         
"badgeClass": "badge-primary"{% endif %}},{% endfor %}
```